# Bathroom exhaust fan issue after new switch install

Tags: electrical, bathroom

I just installed a new Leviton Switch for my bathroom exaust fan/light. After turning the power back on the fan is now on all the time and the switch only controls the light, all available wires are connected, not sure what's going on. I have 2 cables coming into the box where the switch is.  One carries red, black, white and ground, the other is just black, white and ground. The switch i bought has only one black, red and white wire coming off of it. I assume connected one too many wires?

I have not connected the yellow wire to anything
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A photo of the wiring would help , but it sounds like you have 2 wires going to the fan and light and 1 hot and got them mixed up. Mark all 3 wires going to the switch 1,2,3 or a b c. Basically you need to swap the 1 wire that is all alone with one of the 2 on the other side. Now it will work or the light will be on all the time , if the light is on all the time the 1 wire on the 1 side of the switch needs to be swapped with the wire that has been on the other side all the time.

Comment: Ive added some photos, im trying to understand what you've said, although im pretty novice, would you mean move one of the black wires over to the red connection?

Comment: Ok I see 2 cables, the white black is probably the feeder from the breaker panel. The red white black is the wiring going to the fan and the light.  I can’t make out the connections but the black coming in on the black white is your line voltage this should go to the switch, the return from the other side of the switch should go to the red and black. I believe this would be the correct wiring or how I would wire it. It appears you have a smart switch that requires a white “neutral” to power the switch this should not affect the issue you have. I believe your blacks are swapped as a start point

Comment: Ok, so im pretty sure that's how i ended up doing it, i have been successful in getting it to work properly. It was indeed a misplaced wire that had the fan running constantly. Thanks for taking the time to comment and offer advice!